# Extract values from fields in an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, data-extraction

I have a collection in MongoDB with many documents that have the same structure.

When I perform a find query with some filters over the collection with this code:

```js
Comment.find(
        {
            "data.time.s": {
                "$gte": "2019-05-13",
                "$lte": "2019-05-27"
            }
        },
        {
            "data.iaqi.co.v": "$data.iaqi.co.v",
            "data.time.s": "$data.time.s",
            "_id": 0

        }, function (error, datos) {

            console.log(datos)

        });
```

I get the following output when I console.log(datos):

```js
[
  { 
    "data" : {
        "iaqi" : {
            "co" : {
                "v" : 3.2
            }
        }, 
        "time" : {
            "s" : "2019-05-14 12:00:00"
        }
    }
},
{ 
    "data" : {
        "iaqi" : {
            "co" : {
                "v" : 4.7
            }
        }, 
        "time" : {
            "s" : "2019-05-15 00:00:00"
        }
    }
  }
]
```

The array contains more than 2 objects, but for the purpose of the example I just put 2 of them.

All of the objects in the array have the same structure, just the values of **"v"** and **"s"** change on each object.

I just need to extract the values of fields **"v"** and **"s"** from each object and save them in a CSV file with this exact format:

```
Date,Value
2019-05-14 12:00:00,3.2
2019-05-15 00:00:00,4.7
2019-05-17 05:00:00,1
2019-05-19 20:00:00,2.3
2019-05-28 08:00:00,33.4
2019-05-28 10:00:00,18.8
2019-05-28 12:00:00,11.5
2019-05-28 13:00:00,12.4
2019-05-29 06:00:00,6.4
```

Right now I'm doing some tests trying first to show the mentioned values from the array in console with a for loop (instead of just the console.log(datos) in the first code):

```
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
                console.log(datos[i]['data'['time'['s']]]);
            }
```

But I get the following output in the console:

```
undefined
undefined
```

Obviously my syntax is incorrect, but I don't know where is the problem.
What would be the exact syntax to access the array and get the desired values?

Thank you very much to everyone that can throw some light into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close here. Try this syntax. Instead of nesting those items, separate them like such:

```
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
  console.log(datos[i]['data']['time']['s']);
}
```

You could also use dot notation to find what you're after:

```
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
  console.log(datos[i].data.time.s);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gn7kyhuz/

```js
var datos = [
  { 
    "data" : {
        "iaqi" : {
            "co" : {
                "v" : 3.2
            }
        }, 
        "time" : {
            "s" : "2019-05-14 12:00:00"
        }
    }
},
{ 
    "data" : {
        "iaqi" : {
            "co" : {
                "v" : 4.7
            }
        }, 
        "time" : {
            "s" : "2019-05-15 00:00:00"
        }
    }
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
  console.log(datos[i]['data']['time']['s']);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your fast answer, but it's strange, here in the code snippet everything works perfect, but when I run the same code in my app I get again this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined". I think it may be because the output from the Find is not closed with the square brackets (making it an effective Array) as I thought. Is there a way to enclose the output with square brackets with some operator within the Find syntax?

Comment: Searching around I found that using "var datos2 = JSON.stringify(datos)" I can get the output surrounded with square brackets inside **datos2** variable, but when I try to run the for loop again, I get the same error that can't read the property of undefined. Any idea of what's going on here? Thank you!

Comment: @AlejandroRossi Hey man sorry I'm just seeing your comments now. I take it you got your code to work then?

Comment: No problem mate, I wasn't able to access the data on the server-side, so my new question was how to send the variable back to client-side and work with it there: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459427/) Thankfully got answered and now I'm trying to do what I was trying here (the part of generating the custom CSV). Thanks again!