# Send data from NodeJS back to same html page after form submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, response

In an HTML page called "history.html", I have a form with the POST method that I submit to NodeJS server to make some operations.

```html
<form action="/history/find" method="POST">

some form stuff

</form>
```

This is the code on the server that receives the form and makes some operations:

```js
router.post("/history/find", function (req, res) {

    var fechaInicial = req.body.fechaInicial;
    var fechaFinal = req.body.fechaFinal;
    var contaminante = req.body.contaminante;

    Comment.find(
        {
            "data.time.s": {
                "$gte": fechaInicial,
                "$lte": fechaFinal
            }
        },
        {
            [contaminante]: 1,
            "data.time.s": 1,
            "_id": 0
        }, function (error, datos) {

            res.send(datos);

        });

});
```

The resulting output of this particular **Find** operation is an set of many JSON objects (they are not surrounded with square brackets like in an Array), in this example, I just put 2 of them:

```js
    {
        "data": {
            "iaqi": {
                "co": {
                    "v": 3.2
                }
            },
            "time": {
                "s": "2019-05-14 12:00:00"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "iaqi": {
                "co": {
                    "v": 4.8
                }
            },
            "time": {
                "s": "2019-05-15 00:00:00"
            }
        }
    }
```

What I need to achieve, is to somehow send back the variable **datos** that contains the above result, back to the same HTML where I submitted the form.

If I use the **res.send(datos)**, what I get is the data itself represented on the browser. I need to get back to the HTML page but having the variable available to use it and perform other operations directly on the page.

I have been searching the web with no luck on how to do this.
Thank you very much to everyone that can help me with this.

Comment: why you can't use `res.send(JSON.stringify(datos))` and in the HTML Page `JSON.parse` it again?

Comment: If I use `res.send(JSON.stringify(datos))` I just get the same output but surrounded with square brackets (as an Array) on the HTML page, I don't know how to get back to the same page but just with a new variable available with the data inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't send data to an HTML page.** HTML is a static file format and cannot receive data by itself. A server can, but not an HTML file.

What you can do however, is intercept your post request on the client side, send it to the client using [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and receiving back the data on the client side again, then do whatever you want when the script receives `datos`. Basically everything happens between the JavaScript part of the page and the Node server that receives POST data and sends back `datos`.

Here's a simple example of how you can intercept the POST request on the client side:

```js
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = evt => {

  // don't submit the form via the default HTTP redirect
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  // get the form values
  const formData = {
    name1: document.querySelector('input[name=name1]').value,
    name2: document.querySelector('input[name=name2]').value
  }
  console.log('formData:', formData);
  
  // send the form encoded in JSON to your server
  fetch('https://your-domain.com/path/to/api', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
  })
  
  // receive datos from the server
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(datos => {/* do what you want here */})
  
  // catch potential errors
  .catch(err => console.log('an error happened: '+err));
  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="name1" value="value1">
  <input name="name2" value="value2">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PS: The above snippet will fail with a network error because only the client-side script is present - there is nothing running at `https://your-domain.com/path/to/api`, but you already included the right server code in your question. Just end the server script by `res.send(datos)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Nino! Now I know why I wasn't able to find answers to my problem as I was asking the wrong way. With the way you said I'm able to catch on the client-side the Array containing all the data from the query.

Comment: Yes exactly, your question was a perfect example of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ;)